# Normalization: Euclidean distance between a numpy array and one point

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

I have a numpy array (68x2) which correspond to 68 different points of a detected face.

```
[16.0000 93.0000]
[17.0000 116.0000]
[20.0000 139.0000]
[25.0000 162.0000]
[33.0000 184.0000]
[47.0000 205.0000]
[66.0000 219.0000] ... until 68
```

These points have the origin at the left bottom corner of the picture. I want to normalize according to a new center. Two questions, is there a way to do this without a loop? And is this the correct way to normalize according to a new origin?

```
new_origin = [112,135]
new_X
for point in X[0][0]:
    new_X.append(point-new_origin)
```

Comment: I don't think "normalizing according to an origin" has any well-defined meaning, so you need to be more specific if you want us to verify whether what you are doing is correct.  What your current code does is representing the same points with respect to a translated coordinate system with origin at `new_origin`.  It is very well possible that this is what you want.

Comment: And regarding avoiding the loop, you should simply be able to use `new_X = X - new_origin`  (assuming that `X` actually has shape `(68, 2)`, as you claim, though you code suggests otherwise).

Comment: @SvenMarnach I am pre-processing images where I find 68 points describing the face: nose, mouth, eyes, etc. Since I'm interested in the position of these points (The points of a happy face should be in different position from a sad face). So I want to specify a new origin (which should be near the nose) and then translate all the other points to this new axis. I hope this clarifies more the situation.

Comment: Yup, this is what subtracting the coordinates of the new origin does.  There's a whole lot of other transformations you could apply for "normalization", though, like scaling, rotation or non-linear transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to translate those points, all you need to do is subtract a value to the left column (X values) and another to the right column (Y values):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> a[:,0] = a[:,0] - 112
>>> a[:,1] = a[:,1] - 135
>>> a
array([[-112, -134],
       [-110, -132],
       [-108, -130],
       [-106, -128],
       [-104, -126]])
```

You can do directly with [`np.subtract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html):

```
>>> np.subtract(a, [112, 135])
array([[-112, -134],
       [-110, -132],
       [-108, -130],
       [-106, -128],
       [-104, -126]])
```

or just :

```
>>> a - [112, 135]
array([[-112, -134],
       [-110, -132],
       [-108, -130],
       [-106, -128],
       [-104, -126]])
```

Note that with numpy, you almost never have to manually iterate over each element.